# Type mismatch when using Numpy's ifft

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, ifft

guys.

Im performing some FFT's in python to test a vocoder algorithm, but in this code line

```
for i in range(0, duration_s, Nfft):
    output_time[i:i+Nfft] = np.fft.ifft( np.multiply(carr_fft, np.fft.fft(in_samples[i:i+Nfft]) , Nfft) )
```

It yields the Error Message: 
    TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType

It's not a size mismatch issue, I got that covered up (plus, the error message explicitly says it's a Type Mismatch). Any ideas?

Comment: What is Nfft in the above code??

Comment: The number of samples over which the FFT is computed. In this case, 2048.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using

```
numpy.empty()
```

to create the output_time array with an incorrect shape argument. I was actually creating a matrix with a single element, which was the array I wanted, since that when I printed the array, it came out enclosed in two square brackets instead of one. I solved this issue by using

```
np.zeros(duration_s, np.int16, 'C')`
```

and it now works correctly.